# The economics of batching transactions on main net

Tags: optimization, sendtransaction, batch

I want to know if it is feasible to achieve even a marginal saving on gas fees if you were to write a smart contract to send N transactions in batch as opposed to making N separate transactions.

Given the 200 gas-unit per character of byte code cost for deploying and interacting with a smart contract that batch sends transactions, is it theoretically possible to achieve this? Even small amounts of < 5% savings have economies of scale.

This is the first smart contract I've ever written. I'd be really appreciative if people could point how if there are things I could do to minimize the byte code of it by:

- refactoring
- redesigning the contract so that we have a system of interacting contracts that could do the same thing

```
// gas estimates (greater than 10 * standard_transaction_cost)
//{
//    "Creation": {
//        "codeDepositCost": "240000",
//        "executionCost": "48740",
//        "totalCost": "288740"
//    },
//    "External": {
//        "addCashouts(address[],uint256[])": "infinite",
//        "processCashouts()": "infinite"
//    }
//} 

pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

contract BatchCashout {
    // fake address 
    address owner = 0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000;
    bool processed = false;

    function processCashouts() external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the contract owner can process cashouts");
        require(!processed, "Cashouts have already been processed");

        address payable[] memory recipients = new address payable[](9);
        recipients[0] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[1] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[2] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[3] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[4] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[5] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[6] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[7] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[8] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);
        recipients[9] = payable(0x9709bA41A4778cad5616d52F25C7700000000000);

        recipients[0].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[1].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[2].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[3].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[4].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[5].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[6].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[7].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[8].transfer(1 ether);
        recipients[9].transfer(1 ether);

        processed = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shall check out [MakerDAO’s multicall contract](https://github.com/makerdao/multicall) on the Ethereum mainnet; which is deployed at [0xeefBa1e63905eF1D7ACbA5a8513c70307C1cE441](https://etherscan.io/address/0xeefBa1e63905eF1D7ACbA5a8513c70307C1cE441).

Below is an example calling the smart contract with Makerdao’s helper library [multicall.js](https://github.com/makerdao/multicall.js?files=1):

```
const multicall = require("@makerdao/multicall")

const config = {
    rpcUrl: "https://your-rpc-endpoint/12345",
    multicallAddress: "0xeefba1e63905ef1d7acba5a8513c70307c1ce441"
};

const addressArr = [
  "0x2B6ee955a98cE90114BeaF8762819d94C107aCc7",
  "0x2bB42C655DdDe64EE508a0Bf29f9D1c6150Bee5F"
];

async function main() {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  console.log("Started...");

  const calls = [];

  // Retrieve the Ether balance of each Ethereum address in addressArr using the multicall library.
  for (let i = 0; i < addressArr.length; i++) {
      const callObj = {
          call: [
              'getEthBalance(address)(uint256)',
              addressArr[i]
          ],
          returns: [
              [`ETH_BALANCE ${addressArr[i]}`, val => val / 10 ** 18]
          ]
      };
      calls.push(callObj);
  }

  const result = await multicall.aggregate(calls, config);
  console.log(result);

  const timeFromStart = Date.now() - startTime;
  console.log(`Result received in ${timeFromStart / 1000} seconds`);
}

main();
```

The `main` function iterates through each address in the `addressArr` array and creates a call object for each address. These call objects use the multicall library to retrieve the Ether balance for each address.

Once all of the call objects have been created and pushed to the `calls` array, the multicall library's `aggregate` function is called with the array of call objects and the configuration object. This function aggregates the results of all of the calls into a single object, which is stored in the `result` variable.

You can use it to send ethers or call write contract methods too.

Gas-wise, based on my testing, it doesn't make much differences. The benefit of using multicall contract is its result is enforced to be in the same block. Which is handy sometimes.